# import statement for mysql-connector is not working in python

Tags: python, mysql

This import statement is not working and having error.

```
import mysql.connector as mc
```

I dont use any datetime function in my file but it shows these errors.Where am i going wrong?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\combo.py", line 9, in <module>
    import mysql.connector as mc
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    import dns.resolver
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dns\resolver.py", line 38, in <module>
    import dns.query
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\dns\query.py", line 42, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import exceptions
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\exceptions.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .packages.six.moves.http_client import IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 670, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 583, in module_from_spec
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 234, in create_module
    return self.load_module(spec.name)
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 209, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 118, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 87, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\client.py", line 71, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email._policybase import compat32
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
    from email.utils import _has_surrogates
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\utils.py", line 33, in <module>
    from email._parseaddr import quote
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\email\_parseaddr.py", line 16, in <module>
    import time, calendar
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\calendar.py", line 50, in <module>
    class _localized_month:
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\calendar.py", line 52, in _localized_month
    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
  File "C:\Users\mg kaung sat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\calendar.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    _months = [datetime.date(2001, i+1, 1).strftime for i in range(12)]
AttributeError: AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date'
```

Comment: Do you have any module/file in your project directory named `datetime.py`?

Comment: no i dont have any datetime file

Comment: Are you completely sure? Any other module/file added in the system path? Try to add `import datetime` in the header of your main script and then a `print(datetime.__file__)`. The error you're reporting is most likely due to *another* `datetime` file or module that is being loaded.

Comment: i found it I didnt create datetime file but it is already in folder.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

###### Bash: `$ python3 -m pip install mysql-connector`

###### windows: `PS pip install mysql-connector`

python code: `db = mysql.connector.connect(host="host_name/IP", user="username", password="password", database="database_name", auth_plugin="mysql_native_password") c = db.cursor()`

Comment: Please read the question more carefully, including the comment section, before trying to answer: the problem clearly presented in the *import* section, and the question has already been answered, as the issue was that there was another file named `datetime.py` in the project directory. Besides that, an answer should not contain only code or commands, but some minimal explanation should be provided. Please read [answer].